# Trigger Function Doesn't Update the Specified Table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table, payment_detail, that is comprised of an inner join from two other tables (customer & payment), created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS payment_detail AS
SELECT customer.customer_id, customer.first_name, customer.last_name, payment.payment_id, payment.amount)
FROM payment
INNER JOIN customer ON payment.customer_id = customer.customer_id;
```

Now I want to create a trigger function that will update this detail table. This is my current trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_payment_detail()
   RETURNS TRIGGER
   LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
   AS
$$
BEGIN
   UPDATE payment_detail
      SET
      customer_id = customer.customer_id,
      first_name = customer.first_name,
      last_name = customer.last_name,
      payment_id = payment.payment_id,
      amount = payment.amount
      FROM
         payment
         INNER JOIN customer ON payment.customer_id = customer.customer_id
      WHERE customer.customer_id = payment_detail.customer_id;
      RETURN NULL;
END;
$$

CREATE TRIGGER payment_detail_change
   AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT
   ON payment
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_payment_detail();
```

So, the way it's supposed to work is that when an INSERT or UPDATE operation occurs on the payment table, the trigger function is invoked and the update_payment_detail() procedure is executed, which should  result in the payment_detail table being updated. I test the trigger by inserting a new row into the payment table:

```
INSERT INTO payment(customer_id, staff_id, rental_id, amount, payment_date)
VALUES (1, 2, 1849, 4.25, now());
```

The payment table updates perfectly fine; I can see the inserted row. However, the table targeted for the trigger to update, payment_detail, does not show the new row. So the trigger fails to update the payment_detail table. How could I resolve this, based on the code above?

Comment: 1) Actually it is updating everything in the `payment_detail` table that satisfies `WHERE customer.customer_id = payment_detail.customer_id;` with the same data. 2) If the `customer_id` in the `payment` INSERT does not exist in  `payment_detail`  then there will be nothing to update. 3) In the function you are doing an UPDATE which means you will be overwriting the existing `customer_id` row. If you want a new row for each payment then you need to be INSERTing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) Should you insert a new row in table `payment_detail` when inserting a new row in table `payment` ? If so, you have to create two separated trigger functions `insert_payment_detail()` and `update_payment_detail()`.

(b) In the trigger function you have to refer to the fields of the current row which is inserted/updated in table payment by using the `NEW` variable, see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html).

As a result, the trigger functions may be :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_payment_detail()
   RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS
$$
BEGIN
   INSER INTO payment_detail (customer_id, first_name, last_name, payment_id, amount )
      SELECT NEW.customer_id, customer.first_name, customer.last_name, NEW.payment_id, NEW.amount
      FROM customer
      WHERE customer.customer_id = NEW.customer_id;
      RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ ;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_payment_detail
   AFTER INSERT ON payment
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_payment_detail();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_payment_detail()
   RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS
$$
BEGIN
   UPDATE payment_detail
      SET
      customer_id = NEW.customer_id,
      first_name = customer.first_name,
      last_name = customer.last_name,
      payment_id = NEW.payment_id,
      amount = NEW.amount
      FROM customer
      WHERE customer_id = NEW.customer_id;
      RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ ;

CREATE TRIGGER update_payment_detail
   AFTER UPDATE ON payment
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_payment_detail();
```

(c) Instead of duplicating the data from tables `customer` and `payment` into table `payment_detail`, you could create a view `payment_detail`, see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-views.html) :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW payment_detail (customer_id, first_name, last_name, payment_id, amount ) AS
SELECT customer.customer_id, customer.first_name, customer.last_name, payment.payment_id, payment.amount)
FROM payment
INNER JOIN customer ON payment.customer_id = customer.customer_id ;
```